# HTML elements in the browser appearing as inline instead as block elements

Tags: html, element, inline

My following code for a simple webpage on the browser:

The buttons on the webpage show up as inline elements instead of of one on top of the other consecutively. Happens as well with using flexbox. Items within the container become inline without stating display: flex-inline.

[image]

```html
<h1 id="id1">My Heading 1</h1>

<p id="demo"></p>

<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id1').style.color = 'red'">
    Click Me!</button>

<button onclick="displayDate()">Try it</button>
```

I tried adding a `<br>` tag

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review the guidelines for [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what makes a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It would be very helpful if you could edit the question so your code would reproduce your issue if others copy and paste it into their own IDEs, and additionally you should describe explicitly what error messages you’re seeing and where. Right now this question needs more details and clarity before it can be answered.

Answer (score 1):

Buttons are inline elements (well, inline-block) by default.

When you make an element `display: flex` or `display: flex-inline` its *children* are arranged in a row (by default) or column (if you specify `flex-direction: column`).

The difference between `flex` and `flex-inline` is how the *parent* element is rendered, not the children.

---

If you want the buttons displayed on consecutive lines then you can:

- use a `<br>` between them (without involving flexbox) *or*
- put each on in a separate block element such as a `<div>` (also without involving flexbox)  *or*
- numerous other options

I can't infer the semantics of your data (largely because it seems to be a mishmash of demo elements and not a straight-forward text) so I can't comment on which option(s) would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

`<button>` is not a block element. To stack them on top of each other,

1- one way is to wrap them in `<div>`s

```html
 <h1 id="id1">My Heading 1</h1>

<p id="demo"></p>
<div>
    <button type="button" 
    onclick="document.getElementById('id1').style.color = 'red'">
    Click Me!</button>
</div>
<div>
    <button onclick="displayDate()">Try it</button>
</div>
```

2- Another is to use `display: block` style on them.

```
<button style="display: block"></button>
```

3- Or to wrap both of them in a `<div>` with display set to `flex` and `flex-direction` to `column`

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column">
    <button type="button" 
    onclick="document.getElementById('id1').style.color = 'red'">
    Click Me!</button>
    <button onclick="displayDate()">Try it</button>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no such thing as `<button />` It always requires a closing tag.

Answer (score 0):

By default, buttons have a display of `inline-block`. If you want to change that, explicitly set the `display`.

```css
button {
    display: block;
}
```